# Vim's Ruby option is not enabled

Tags: ruby, vim

I just started learning Ruby and I ran this command:

```
vim --version
```

The output looks like this (look at the yellow circle):

[image]

Which means that my Vim does not include the 'ruby' function.
But it seems my Vim supports Ruby fairly well:

[image]

q1: Is there any problem with my Ruby programming with the `-ruby`?

q2: How can I enable Ruby function in Vim?

Comment: You probably don't need it unless you have a plugin that requires ruby. But to get ruby support you need to recompile vim (or get your package manager to do it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functionality on the second screenshot is given by installing the [vim-ruby](http://vimawesome.com/plugin/vim-ruby) plugin.

The internal Ruby support is to allow people to write plugins and scripts for Vim using Ruby and it's not strictly necessary for what you seem to want to accomplish.

If you **REALLY** want to add Ruby support, you can always build Vim from source (or get a package with it already built). I suggest you to look into [Vim's homepage](http://www.vim.org/) for more info on this matter.

Answer (score 1):

The difference you are missing is between using Vim to program in a language such as Ruby, and using a given language *to program Vim*.

Writing Ruby code using Vim is enabled by Vim's native syntax files, as well as various third-party plugins available for Vim. This is the case for many, many languages, not only those mentioned in the `:version` screen (Perl, Python, and Ruby). You can use Vim to write code in C, Scala, PHP, Javascript, and many other languages, with support for syntax highlighting, smart indenting, and so on.

Writing Vim functions and plugins can only be done in a small set of languages. Natively, Vim code is always written in its own language, Vimscript. However, Vimscript is notoriously difficult to deal with, and most people will not already know it. So Vim also has the ability to use plugins written in other languages, such as Python or Ruby. This enables people to use a more familiar language for plugin development.

However, using those languages requires binding to an interpreter for the language, and this must be decided at the time Vim is compiled. The `:version` screen is telling you that for your installation of Vim, the Ruby support was not enabled, so you can not write plugins using Ruby, nor can you use any available plugins which were written in Ruby.

Notice that `+python` is present, so you can use Python plugins (but `-python3` is there too, meaning that you do not have Python 3.x support built in).